# how to post json object array to a web api

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

How can I post a JSON array to a Web API? It's working for single object.

This is what I've tried, but the controller seems to be returning `0` rather than the expected `3`.

This is my JSON:

```
var sc = [{
              "ID": "5",
              "Patient_ID": "271655b8-c64d-4061-86fc-0d990935316a",
              "Table_ID": "Allergy_Trns",
              "Checksum": "-475090533",
              "LastModified": "2015-01-22T20:08:52.013"
          },
          {
              "ID": "5",
              "Patient_ID": "271655b8-c64d-4061-86fc-0d990935316a",
              "Table_ID": "Allergy_Trns",
              "Checksum": "-475090533",
              "LastModified": "2015-01-22T20:08:52.013"
          },
          {
              "ID": "5",
              "Patient_ID": "271655b8-c64d-4061-86fc-0d990935316a",
              "Table_ID": "Allergy_Trns",
              "Checksum": "-475090533",
              "LastModified": "2015-01-22T20:08:52.013"
          }];
```

AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
           url: urlString,
           type: 'POST',
           data: sc,
           dataType: 'json',
           crossDomain: true,
           cache: false,
           success: function (data) { console.log(data); }
        });
```

Web API controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public string PostProducts([FromBody]List<SyncingControl> persons)
{
    return persons.Count.ToString(); // 0, expected 3
}
```

Comment: I don't imagine this is it, but have you tried using dev tools in the browser to just confirm that the payload is even being sent? I know nothing about Web API so perhaps this isn't the most likely cause, but I can imagine something client-side setting `sc` equal to `null` before the request gets fired off, which seems like it could do this.

Comment: Any errors in the browser console? You are missing a double quote in the first person object in sc.

Comment: no any error on console

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is an error in the json `Table_ID": "Allergy_Trns"` should be `"Table_ID": "Allergy_Trns"`.

Missing double quote.

**Update**

You need to make sure that you are sending your parameters as json as follows:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: urlString,
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(sc),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        crossDomain: true,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) { console.log(data); }
    });
```

Notice the `JSON.stringify(sc)`, @herbi is partly correct too about specifying a content type.

**Screen grab**

[image: **Screen grab**]

Comment: hutchonoid: its missed here not in my code sorry for that.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the content-type header to the ajax request, so that WebAPI is able to understand the request and use the correct formatter to deserialize the data:

```js
$.ajax({
           url: urlString,
           type: 'POST',
           data: sc,
           dataType: 'json',
           contentType: "application/json",
           crossDomain: true,
           cache: false,
           success: function (data) { console.log(data); }
        });
```

Comment: sorry, it is "contentType", not "content-Type"

Answer (score 1):

You can set the Content-Type on **beforeSend** which will insure that your json data matches with your server object

```js
$.ajax({
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        },
           url: urlString,
           type: 'POST',
           data: sc,
           dataType: 'json',
           contentType: "application/json",
           crossDomain: true,
           cache: false,
           success: function (data) { console.log(data); }
        });
```