# Pass List object to C# Web Api POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am trying to pass a List to my Web API but I keep getting a null value. I am converting the list in to a string before passing it to the API. Any ideas how can I bind it correctly?

```
public async Task<ReturnViewModel> ModContactsAsync(List<ContactsDTO> Contacts)
 {
     ReturnViewModel vm = new ReturnViewModel();

    var postContactsUri = new UriBuilder(AppConfig.ServiceUrlBase);

    //Converts object into a string
    var jsonObject = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Contacts);


    postContactsUri.Path = string.Format(POST_CONTACTS_API_PATH, jsonObject);
    //Calls API
    var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(postContactsUri.ToString());

    return vm;
}
```

POST - API CALL List prod is null

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("contacts/Save")]
[ResponseType(typeof(ReturnMessage))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ModContacts([FromBody] List<ContactsDTO> prods)
{
    try
    {
        await Task.Delay(10);

        return Ok();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new PropertyPortalWebApiException(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Contact information does not exist.", ex);
    }
  }
```

Comment: You are trying to put the contacts into the URL, but then reading them from the request Body?

Comment: Try to adjust the `PostAsync` to look like this: `var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(POST_CONTACTS_API_PATH, new System.Net.Http.StringContent(jsonObject, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));`

Comment: @mike123 I still get a null.

Comment: @Rhumborl what do you recommend?

Comment: How in the world would u receive a list by url, and after that trying to receive them by body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. Just add the Contacts object to the PostAsync to the second parameter and voila. You don't need to convert the object to JSON.

```
public async Task<ReturnViewModel> ModContactsAsync(List<ContactsDTO> Contacts)
{
    ReturnViewModel vm = new ReturnViewModel();

    var postContactsUri = new UriBuilder(AppConfig.ServiceUrlBase);

    postContactsUri.Path = string.Format(POST_CONTACTS_API_PATH, jsonObject);
    //Add Contacts to second parameter
    var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(postContactsUri.ToString(), Contacts);

return vm;
```

}

Comment: What will be the sending mechanism if I have to pass the list of some object inside main object. Please refer question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51171160/pass-list-of-object-with-main-object-in-web-api-from-asp-net-mvc).

Answer (score 1):

You should simply search and understand GET/POST difference and how to post with HttpClient.

First you are adding your content in URL and trying to post it with HttpClient.

```
var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(postContactsUri.ToString());
```

And then in your API you are reading the object FromBody which has been passed in URL.

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ModContacts([FromBody] List<ContactsDTO> prods)
```

The signature of PostAsync method is

```
public Task PostAsync(Uri uri, HttpContent content)
```

So you should pass URL in first parameter and your list object in form of HttpContent as second parameter.

Or you can use PostAsJsonAsync extension method.

Comment: Perfect .Thank you

Comment: @AmilaThennakoon, glad you found it helpful!

Answer (score 0):

```
public IActionResult GetAllContacts()
{
     List<Contacts> contacts = contactService.RetrieveAllContacts();
     return Json(contacts);
}
```

So in theory the above would be your API.  A user would request `GetAllContacts`, in which you would get the contacts from the database, then return via Json.

The consumer would then write code to consume:

```
var request = CreateWebRequest(url) as HttpWebRequest;
if(request != null)
     using(var response = request.GetResponse.GetResponseStream())
          var content = Json.DeserializeObject(request.ReadToEnd());
```

Something like the above, should return a `List<Contacts>` for you.

I believe that is what you're trying to do.

---

Update:

I noticed that you want the consumer to save the data.  You would do something along these lines:

```
public IActionResult SaveContact([FromBody] List<Contacts>)
{
     // Validate and Save
}
```

The consumer would do either Ajax or something a long these lines:

```
List<Contact> contacts = contactService.GetAllContacts(); // User would have a collection for you.
var post = Json.SerializeObject(contacts);

var request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = ...
request.ContentLength = post.Length;
request.UserAgent = ...
request.Accept = ...
request.Referer = ...

using(var writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream())
{
     writer.Write(post); 
     request.GetResponse();
     request.Close();
}
```

You don't need all the parameters for request I denoted, but they exist.  Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Greg, I am trying to pass a List to the API. How can I pass the above to the API call?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28106872/how-to-post-json-object-array-to-a-web-api

Comment: @Apollo Through Ajax or C#?  I made the code more explicit rather than `var`.

Comment: How do you pass this to PostAsync?

Comment: @AluanHaddad `WebRequest` and `HttpWebRequest` don't implement `IDispose` by default.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my case which was similar to yours (solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117101/posting-jsonobject-with-httpclient-from-web-api#39414248)).

Basically:

```
public async Task<ReturnViewModel> ModContactsAsync(List<ContactsDTO> Contacts)
{
    ReturnViewModel vm = new ReturnViewModel();

    var bodyContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Contacts);

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var response = await client.PostAsync(AppConfig.ServiceUrlBase, new StringContent(bodyContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

        return responseString.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }

    return vm;
}
```

As you already know from previous comments, client can't send a list as a query parameter and the server is expecting it on the body.

With the code above, the client sends the list in the **body** and the server reads it from the **body**.

**Never** send a list as a query parameter, even if it's a small list.
There is a limitation on URL length and also why exposing your parameters on the URL if the POST method allows you to use the request body to send information...

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's null that is because you try to send a model, but in another method, you try to get the list of objects.
You must get the object that involves the list of objects after that your request will read.

ModContacts([FromBody] ContactDTO prod)

In ContactDTO  you must have a list of object that will serializable

Comment: I am not sending a model. I am sending a list.