# What is the correct way to POST arrays (Lists) of objects in .NET Core 2?

Tags: .net, json, rest, .net-core

I have an API method with this signature:

`public async Task<IActionResult> PostCompanies([FromBody] List<Company> companies)`

...and the auto generated swagger docs show that the JSON should be a plain array:

```
 [  
       {
          "fuelSiteId":228972,
          "name": "foo"
       },
       {
          "fuelSiteId":300000010,
          "name": "bar"
       }
 ]
```

However, if I post this back, it doesn't work and I get the error:

"Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Company' because the type requires a JSON object"

The fix is to add the array to a dummy property:

```
{  
    data: [
       {
          "fuelSiteId":228972,
          "name": "foo"
       },
       {
          "fuelSiteId":300000010,
          "name": "bar"
       }
    ]
}
```

But everything I'm finding on this site implies this shouldn't be necessary and isn't how you'd normally do it in REST.  Additionally, it means what the auto-generated docs say isn't actually what should be posted!

Which is wrong?  My API code or the auto-gen Swagger docs or something else?

Ideally I would prefer my API to accept the 'plain' version as this seems more standard and more natural.

Comment: Related: [Is a list/array valid JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19623339/1220550)

Comment: Can you give us an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please

Comment: The correct parameter for your method should be a type that takes an object with a int property and a string property.. FromBody is to handle the post of form data. so if you remove the [FromBody] maybe it works already?
The Company type has to have a FuelSiteID (int) and Name (string) property though.

Comment: Yeah the JSON validates fine.

Comment: @rmjoia My real object has a couple of dozen properties, but I've tried removing FromBody and it doesn't fix the problem. It still needs it assigned to a dummy property to work.

Comment: I usually use an array like `Company[]` or an `IEnumerable<Company>`, but anyway it should work fine. As already asked, please share a [mcve]

Comment: I have found out that I had two duplicate methods and it was hitting a method of the same name which was only expecting a single object.   I will delete this question in a couple of days as an "invalid question".

Answer (score 1):

This also works without having to wrap in another type, give it a try.
I've tested with Postman

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult InsertPatientAppointment([FromBody] List<Company> companies)
    {
        return new JsonResult(companies.Select(c =>
            new
            {
                c.FuelSiteId,
                c.Name,
            }
        ));
    }

    public class Company
    {
        [JsonProperty("fuelSiteId")]
        public int FuelSiteId
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
```

[image: screenshot on the breackpoint]

You can also check other resource on SO [how to post json object array to a web api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28106872/how-to-post-json-object-array-to-a-web-api) I had to dig a bit myself as I didn't remember anymore how to do this..

As stated at [Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api): "To force Web API to read a complex type from the URI, add the [FromUri] attribute to the parameter."

[Using [FromBody]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api#using-frombody)